# Add an event handler to jqGrid after instantiation

Tags: event-handling, jqgrid

I want to add an event handler to jqGrid (for the onSelectRow event) but after the grid has already been created on the page i.e. I cant hardcode it into the initial jqGrid definition.

I have tried using `setGridParam` to set an event handler for `onSelectRow` but that didnt work :(

```
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', { onSelectRow: function(id){ alert(id); } } );
```

The jqGrid docs are quite difficult to get what you want out of them and I havent found anything regarding this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I just tested to use

```
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', { onSelectRow: function(id){ alert(id); } } );
```

in my code and it works. If jqGrid has already an `onSelectRow` it overwrite the old one event handle. If there are no `onSelectRow` event handler, it add a new handler. So all must work.

If you do will have problem, you should post a code example which reproduce it.

Comment: Hi Oleg - perhaps my version of jQuery? Its working now with exactly the same code, i was playing with different versions of jQuery at the time tho. Thanks for the confirmation anyway :P

Comment: @Oleg, is there a way to register multiple functions to be called on a grid event? For example, I want some basic stuff to always run on loadComplete, but on some grids I have other stuff that belongs there as well.

Comment: @IronicMuffin: It's a good question! There are only one `loadComplete` event. If you describe more exactly your environment and your problem one can suggest the solution.

Comment: @Oleg, I asked it with a little more detail [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776696/is-it-possible-to-bind-multiple-event-handlers-to-jqgrid-events-without-overwriti).