# How to handle a JqGrid event programmatically?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I'm using the [ASP.NET wrapper for JqGrid](http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnet.aspx). I'd like to programmatically wire up handlers for some of the grid's [events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events) (e.g. `gridComplete`, `resizeStop`).

All the examples I've seen have you wire up the event as part of the options when creating the grid object - for example:

```
$("#gridid").jqGrid({
   ...
   onSelectRow: function(){ ... },
   ...
});
```

However, the ASP.NET component does this initial setup for me. I can customize some client-side handlers on the component, like `gridInitialized`; but (bizarrely) only a small subset of the events are exposed this way.

So: Once the grid has initialized, is there a way to attach handlers to its events? I've tried things like

```
$grid.setGridParam("resizeStop", function () { alert("!!") }); // DOESN'T WORK
```

and

```
$grid.resizeStop = function () { alert("!!") }; // DOESN'T WORK
```

and of course the standard jQuery event binding syntax

```
$grid.bind("resizeStop", function () { alert("!!") }) // DOESN'T WORK
```

but none of this works.

Any ideas?

Comment: As a side comment, the incompleteness of the ASP.NET wrapper is really, really maddening. There's so much that you can do using the plain open-source component that's just completely inaccessible if you use the wrapper.

Comment: I agree. I would not have opted to buy the wrapper from Trirand if I knew how utterly incomplete, and at times useless, the wrapper really is. Did you happen to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

You can do change event handler with respect of `setGridParam` method (see a close question [Add an event handler to jqGrid after instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148320/add-an-event-handler-to-jqgrid-after-instantiation/3149534#3149534)). It must work on the same way for commertial and for the open source version of jqGrid. Just try following:

```
$('#gridid').jqGrid('setGridParam', { resizeStop: function(newwidth, index) {
    alert("The column with the index " + index + " has now the width " + newwidth);
} } );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Not sure if whoever up-voted this answer actually got it to work, but nothing happens on my end.

Comment: @Cody: The answer is very old,  but all still work. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/setResizeStop.htm) and resize a column. You will see the alert which was set be the above code.

Comment: Thanks. This method does work, in my case I had the parameters in the method incorrect.