# How do you modify the data returned from an AJAX call before it is rendered in the jqGrid?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

**Background**

I've picked up some incomplete work from another developer that involves displaying the results of a search. His approach was to render the results in an HTML table using inline Javascript and jQuery as follows.

[image: Grid using table and inline Javascript]

I'm trying to finish off the work but I would prefer to write less code and use the jqGrid because it includes sorting functionality, and to get the code tidier. Getting the jqGrid to display the results is easy, but getting the radio buttons in a blank column is harder than I thought it would be.

The version of jqGrid in the application is 3.7.2. The grid needs to have radio buttons on the left for selection to keep things consistent with the rest of the application.

**Where I'm stuck**

There doesn't seem to be a way to have an unbound column in jqGrid. That is, each column seems to need a field in the underlying data. If you do not have a dummy field, then the row data and column headers become misaligned.

I've come across an [example](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) (See Row Editing -> Custom Edit) that returns JSON with a dummy field in the data, and then modifies the grid data to insert buttons.

My preference is to not have the dummy data in there, because it *feels dirty* :) I would like my JSON to only include the data it needs to represent the results of the search. So I was thinking that it would be better to add the dummy field in the script code instead in order to keep the code on the server side clean.

I'm trying to modify the data returned from the AJAX call before jqGrid renders it. I've tried hooking into the `loadComplete` event but when I modify the data it appears to be after it has already rendered.

I've also tried hooking into the `success` event on the `ajaxGridOptions` field of `options` but that seems to totally override the event and jqGrid doesn't render the data.

**How can I modify the data returned from a web service call before jqGrid renders it?**

Comment: What are you doing to the data specifically?  There are a few options, but it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: On the jqGrid I have a blank column that I'm inserting controls into. The example on http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html (Row Editing -> Custom Edit) has a dummy field in the cell array, in the JSON response, but I want to dynamically add the dummy field to the response on the client side before jqGrid sees it and not have the dummy field in the response sent from the server side.

Comment: There are no universal way to modify the data returned from the server **before** processing the data by jqGrid, but if the returned data has JSON format you can convert the data in another format inside of `jsonReader` or use just custom formatter to display the data in another way. Could you include in your question the JavaScript code which defines jqGrid and the full JSON data returned from the server? Could you additionally exactly describe which modifications you want to do? On the example one can find the solution better.

Comment: @oleg - I'm padding the data because if you don't, the data ends up in the wrong columns. The example that I linked above does it with the following code:

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $responce->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
    $responce->rows[$i]['cell']=array("",$row[id],$row[invdate],$row[name],$row[amount],$row[tax],$row[total],$row[note]);
    $i++;
}`

Notice the `""` added as the first field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my previous answer broke sorting so I came up with another solution.

Because jqGrid doesn't provide the hooks to conveniently modify the data, it was necessary to drop back a level and hook into jQuery. I replaced the `$.ajax()` method with my own. Firstly it checks whether the operation is one being initiated by jqGrid and if so, it pads the data, calls the original jqGrid `success` handler, and then adds the radio buttons to the grid. Sorting still works, the datatype is still json, and there are no manual calls to `addJSONData` and I am still able to achieve what I needed from the previous solution. Essentially, making this small jQuery hack allows me to get by without making any jqGrid hacks which is far messier.

```
// Set up $.ajax() hook for modifying the data before jqGrid receives it
if (!this._ajaxOverridden) {
    var oldAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function (options) {
        // Check whether this call is from jqGrid to our web service
        if (options.url == config.eventSearchUrl && options.success) {
            // Wrap the success event handler with our own handler that pads the data and creates the radio buttons
            var oldSuccess = options.success;
            options.success = function () {
                thisEventSearchDialog._padData(arguments[0]);
                oldSuccess.apply(this, arguments);
                thisEventSearchDialog._createRadioButtons();
            }
        }
        oldAjax(options);
    };
    this._ajaxOverridden = true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure out how to do it. Rather than letting **jqGrid** load the data automatically one needs to manually perform the request and then load it via a call to `addJSONData`.

My jqGrid is defined in mark up as follows:

```
<fieldset>            
    <div style="display:none" class="searchResults">
        <table id="eventSearchDialog-results">
        </table>
        <div id="eventSearchDialog-pager">
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

I initialize the grid with the following code:

```
// Initialize the grid
this._searchResults = this._dialog.find("#eventSearchDialog-results");
this._searchResults.jqGrid(
{
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ['', 'Event Name', 'Event Type', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Location', 'Event Country', 'Sports'],
    colModel: [
                { name: 'selector', index: 'selector', width: 30 },
                    { name: 'EventName', index: 'EventName', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter, width: 150 },
                { name: 'EventType', index: 'EventType', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter, width: 120 },
                { name: 'StartDate', index: 'StartDate', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter, width: 100 },
                { name: 'EndDate', index: 'EndDate', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter, width: 100 },
                { name: 'Location', index: 'Location', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter, width: 100 },
                { name: 'EventCountry', index: 'EventCountry', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter, width: 100 },
                { name: 'Sports', index: 'Sports', formatter: jqgridCellFormatter }
                    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [10, 20, 30],
    pager: this._dialog.find("#eventSearchDialog-pager"),
    pginput: true,
    sortname: 'EventName',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    hidegrid: false,
    height: "auto",
    shrinkToFit: true,
    width: 630,
    jsonReader:
                    {
                        page: "pageIndex",
                        total: "pageCount",
                        records: "recordCount",
                        root: "rows",
                        repeatitems: true
                    },
    prmNames:
    {
        page: "pageIndex",
        rows: "pageSize",
        sort: "sortField",
        order: "sortOrder"
    }
}
);
// Set the data type to JSON, we don't do this in the options because it will cause a request to occur,
// but we do need it to be set to JSON so that the calls to addJSONData work later.
this._searchResults.jqGrid("setGridParam", { datatype: "json" });
```

I load the grid with data from a jQuery `$.ajax()` call, and in the `success` event handler I pad the data and then load it into jqGrid using `addJSONData`.

My JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "pageCount":1,
    "pageIndex":1,
    "recordCount":2,
    "rows":
    [
        {"id":3, "cell":["Stevens Event 2", "Commonwealth Games", "03/05/2011", "16/05/2011", "sersdfweqr", "New Zealand", ["Archery"]]},
        {"id":4, "cell":["Test - multiple sports", "Other", "01/05/2011", "30/06/2011", "Kobe", "Japan", ["Judo", "Karate", "Motor Sport", "Motorcycling", "Taekwondo"]]}
    ]
}
```

This is my `success` handler:

```
success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
    // Pad data for our radio button column that has no corresponding field in the data
    for (var counter = 0; counter < data.rows.length; counter++) {
        data.rows[counter].cell.splice(0, 0, null);
    }

    thisEventSearchDialog._searchResults[0].addJSONData(data);
    thisEventSearchDialog._createRadioButtons();
},
```

The jqGrid containing the column of radio buttons for which the dummy data was needed. Without the dummy data, the row data did not match the headers.
[image]

Comment: You don't included the code of `jqgridCellFormatter` which is very important in your case. If you use `repeatitems: true` property of `jsonReader` the data for each column should have be strings and not array. How you want display `Sports` column? Why you don't use the standard `date` formatter for the `StartDate` and `StartDate` columns? I find the usage of `datatype:'local'` and manual call of `addJSONData` very bad workaround. There are better solutions.

Comment: @oleg- So, from the image I've put in the answer, you can see the radio buttons that I've added. This is what I'm trying to achieve. The other developer has other grids in the app that look like this but were made with tables and Javascript. I've been tasked with finishing some work but prefer to use jqGrid rather than messy tables and in-line script. What do you suggest doing to make jqGrid look roughly like the image but not use `addJSONData` and `datatype:'local'`?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, and it may not be applicable to the version of the jqGrid mentioned (3.7.2), but it seems to be related to this: [How to "pre-process" an ajax response before displaying in jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522165/how-to-pre-process-an-ajax-response-before-displaying-in-jqgrid) and if I'm right (about being related) then the correct answer is the `dataFilter` parameter/function of the `ajaxGridOption` parameter. It worked for me.