# Alter the data before displaying it in the grid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, encode

I have a jqGrid that is filled by a JSON request, the thing is that the request back to the server in base64 encoded data and I need to decode the data before assign it to the grid.

Basically I need something like this:

```
$( "#grid" ).jqGrid( {
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ["id", "Num", "Name", "Code"],
    colModel: [
        { name: "id", index: "id", width: 30, sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { name: "num", index: "num", width: 150, sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { name: "name", index: "name", width: 250, sortable: true, resizable: false },
        { name: "code", index: "code", width: 150, sortable: true, resizable: false },
    ],
    multiselect: true,
    width: "760",
    height: "100%",
    heightMetric: "%",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [20,30,60],
    pager: "#pager",
    sortname: "id",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "asc",
    headertitles : true,
    caption: "Loading...",
    beforeProcessing: function(data){
       data = decompress(data); // Like this
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The callback function `beforeProcessing` is the correct place where you can implement all what you need. The exact implementation depends on the format of the data returned by the server. If one uses `datatype: "json"` then the data returned from the server are typically an object which is serializes as JSON string. jqGrid uses internally `jQuery.ajax` which automatically decode the JSON string and convert it back to object. So the input `data` parameter of `beforeProcessing` callback is the object returned from the server. If you don't use any additional `jsonReader` option of jqGrid then jqGrid wait the input data in the standard format described [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data). So you need just fill the expected properties of `data` object (`rows`, `page`, `total` and `records`) based on the input data returned from the server. You don't posted any example of the data returned from the server, so I could give you no more detailed examples.

Comment: I was looging for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462996/how-do-you-modify-the-data-returned-from-an-ajax-call-before-it-is-rendered-in-t).

Comment: @byoigres: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.