# jqGrid - Is it possible to set onSortCol after init?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I've looked through the [jqGrid documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) and a few other SO questions, and pretty much the only documented way to handle `onSortCol` is when you initialize the grid, ie:

```
var myGrid = $("#gridid").jqGrid({
   //...
   onSortCol: function(index, iCol, sortorder) { ... }
});
```

Is there a way to bind to the `onSortCol` event through the `myGrid` reference, after the grid has already been initialized?

Something like:

```
myGrid.onSortCol(function (index, iCol, sortorder)
   {
      //...
   }
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found one solution.  This appears to work well:

```
 myGrid.setGridParam({
     onSortCol: function(index, iCol, sortorder)
     {
         alert("Hello");
     }
 });
```

Comment: +1 seems like the cleanest way to do it using the jqGrid API.

Comment: Yes, it's correct way (see the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3149534/315935) for example). Alternatively you can use `jqGridSortCol` event: `myGrid.bind("jqGridSortCol", function (e, index, iCol, sortOrder]) { alert("in jqGridSortCol");} )`